# Python: Function inside IF. Problems

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to Python. I'm having trouble executing an IF with a function inside. I enclose the code, including the graphic interface in Tkinter. In the same algorithm, I was wrong and i have difficulty in 2 things: write the correct IF conditions, and correctly call the Function inside IF, that is:

```
if categorias == "Phrase of love" and sottocategorias == "Short sentences":
     phrase_example
```

(it's written with errors, I know)

I would like to do that: if in the combobox1 (Categorys) I select the "Phrase of love" item, and then in the combobox2 (Subcategorias) I select the "Short sentences" item (selected both, at the same time, from the two comboboxes) ... then I click on the button and the Function is called (the code has already been written). The task of the Function, as you can see, is to print sentences (from the database) in the multiline textbox.

I looked for other similar questions to avoid asking questions, but didn't understand much considering I just got started with Python. Can you show me where I'm wrong by showing me the correct IF code and Function code? Thank you

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

window=Tk()
window.title("Test")
window.geometry("700x700")
window.configure(bg='#78c030')

### BUTTON ###
def phrase_example(): # setting this to button 2
    cursor.execute('SELECT phrase2, phrase3 FROM allphrase ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 
1')
    word2,word3 = cursor.fetchone()
    text.delete(1.0,END)
    text.insert(tk.END,f"{word2} {word3}")

if categorias == "Phrase of love" and sottocategorias == "Short sentences":
     phrase_example

button2 = Button(window, text="Button2", bg='white', command = phrase_example)
button2.pack()
button2.place(x=5, y=330)

### TEXTBOX MULTILINE ###
text = Text(window,width=63,height=38)
text.pack()
text.place(x=180, y=24)

### CATEGORIA E SOTTOCATEGORIA ###
cat=StringVar()
sub_cat=StringVar()

def change_val(*args):
    if cat.get() == "Phrase of love":
        sottocategorias = ["Short sentences", "Long sentences", "Medium sentences"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    else:
        sottocategorias = ["aaaa"]
        sottocategoria.config(values=sottocategorias)
    
categorias=["Phrase of love", "Phrase of life", "Phrase of spiritual"]
categoria=ttk.Combobox(window,value=categorias,textvariable=cat,width=16)
categoria.place(x=5, y=25)
cat.set("Scegliere categoria")

sottocategorias=["aaaa"]
sottocategoria=ttk.Combobox(window,textvariable=sub_cat,value=sottocategorias,
width=16)
sottocategoria.place(x=5, y=55)
cat.trace("w",change_val)

con = sqlite3.connect('/home/mypc/Scrivania/Test/Database.db')
cursor = con.cursor()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the IF checking inside `phrase_example()`.

Also you need to use `categoria.get() == ...` and `sottocategoria.get() == ...` instead of `categorias == ...` and `sottocategorias == ...`:

```py
def phrase_example():
    if categoria.get() == "Phrase of love" and sottocategoria.get() == "Short sentences":
        cursor.execute('SELECT phrase2, phrase3 FROM allphrase ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        word2,word3 = cursor.fetchone()
        text.delete(1.0,END)
        text.insert(tk.END,f"{word2} {word3}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I had also tried to do this myself, then I preferred to use the "inside" If function, due to various reasons. How can I put the Function inside If? Thank you

Comment: Put `if ...: phrase_example()` inside another function and call this function when the button is clicked.  But this is basically the same as my proposal.  I don't understand why you need such situation.

Comment: Because I will have to add dozens of If's and dozens of Functions. The published code is only an example, to understand how it works. I will have more order with the Functions inside the various Ifs.

If you look above in what I posted, I had already done as you just suggested (with the error of not putting .get and mistakenly using categoryS and subcategoryS), but I was getting an error. I found the error when I called the function by typing phrase_example. Before or after phrase_example, do I have to write nothing more?

Comment: No, your IF statement in your question (even you fix the typos and using `.get()`) is meaningless because at the time it is executed, the two comboboxes are not defined and user interaction is not started.

Comment: Ah OK. For reasons of cleaning and organization of the code (when there will be dozens of If and dozens of Functions), I would need the Function inside If ... as per the question asked. Thank you for your kindness, but unfortunately the answer with the IF inside the Function is not helpful. How can I define the boxes (I'm confused for a moment) and how to proceed to put the function inside IF? Can you show me the code please? Thanks and sorry

Comment: As I already said I don't understand why you need *"function inside IF"*.

Comment: For the sake of organization and code cleansing, as I said before (not in this poor and restricted example of code, but in another small project of mine). Don't look at the code example I posted in the question. It was just an example where, for logic reasons, the Function inside If is not needed. But I need to understand how to use the Function inside If, ​​because I need it for another project (not this one posted) where there will be many Ifs and many Functions. Can you please show me how to use the Function inside IF as I asked in the main question? Thank you

Comment: Ok I put the function inside If. I defined the two comboboxes, with cat = StringVar () and sub_cat = StringVar (). Works well. Only problem that the function is accessed with any item in the combobox2 Subcategory. Not only with Phrase of love >>> Short sentences. Yet, after cat = StringVar () and sub_cat = StringVar (),  I wrote if cat.get == "Phrase of love" and sub_cat.get == "Short sentences":
     phrase_example. Help me, please